# How do I know if qwt is installed correctly?

Tags: qt

I'm just beginning to work with QT and qwt, I installed QT 5.1.1 and then installed QWT 6.1.0 using the instructions that was given :

```
qmake qwt.pro
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install
```

It installed without any errors. But I can't be sure if it's istalled correctly, how do I test it? I even have trouble using qwt! I searched in the widgets in QT designer and didn't find any thing related to qwt in there. I would appreciate it if you could guide me.
Thank you in adnvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html.

Unfortunately it is not that easy to understand about designer plugins, but this is the fault of the designer - not the plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you said I'm using qwt now but I couldn't find a decent way to confirm the correct installation of QWT plugin ...